# How to make a keyword list with enumitem with labels aligned right in the margin?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumitem, description

I kinda succeeded in doing with *without* using the `enumitem` package, by doing this:
*(disregard the lines, it's made with `showframe`)*

```
\newenvironment*{keywordlist}{%
    \list{}{%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{\marginparwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\marglistsep}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
        \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss\marglistfont##1}%
    }%
}{%
    \endlist%
}
```

[image]

This works like a `description` environment, but the labels are moved to the margin. The labels also align to the right, i.e. the text body, separated by `\marglistsep`.
the long label in the middle shows what should happen if the label is too long to fit entirely in the margin.

Now, I tried doing this with the function set provided by `enumitem`, but I got only this far:

```
\newlist{keywordlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[keywordlist]{style=multiline, labelsep=5pt, leftmargin=0pt, labelindent=-\marginparwidth}
```

[image]

This will put the labels into the margin, but I pretty much lost the separator value, and all labels are aligned to the left border, which puts a huge gap between the label and the text body. Which doesn't look too good. I like that I can make this label span multiple lines, which is why I'd like to use that over my first approach.

In essence, I'd kinda like to have *best of both worlds*, so the labels are aligned to the text body, could span multiple lines, but if one of those lines gets too long, it'll push the body contents inward.

Comment: Did you try with `align=right`? And please post a **complete** minimal document people can work with. That is much more useful than mere code fragments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can try with `align` key of `enumitem` and define your own `align` key:

```
 \SetLabelAlign{myright}{strut\smash{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}}
```

and use it as `align=myright`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,showframe}
\SetLabelAlign{myright}{strut\smash{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}}
\newlist{keywordlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[keywordlist]{style=multiline, labelsep=5pt, leftmargin=0pt,align=myright,
           labelindent=-\marginparwidth}
\begin{document}
 \begin{keywordlist}
 \item[yow] So this is some thing
 \item[This is very long item] This is one kind. This is one kind. This is one kind. This is one kind. This is one kind. This is one kind. This is one kind.
 \item[abcde] This is another kind.
 \end{keywordlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But note that if the item label is longer and the description is shorter, you will have the overlapping of the items.

Comment: Any ideas how I could make the labels push the contents inward? This helps a lot such as it is, but pushing contents inward would be a big benefit to me.

Comment: @polemon Will you please elaborate - `pushing contents inward`? Sorry I don't understand well.

Comment: Just like in my opening post: if one of those lines becomes too long, it'll push the contents inward, rather than overlapping them (the "longitemname" in the first picture)

Comment: @polemon That means, you don't want description labels to break in to second line? Use `sameline` instead of `multiline`.